# T-SQL stored procedure - cannot assign output value to variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that finds the current `BatchID` and increments it by 1 and returns the value as an output parameter; however, whenever I use a select statement after it, I get the value set to it before the stored procedure was executed.

Why is this happening?

Execution of the stored procedure:

```
declare @BatchStartTS datetime = getdate()
declare @NewBatchID int = 0

exec dbo.[usp_CreateBatchRecord] @BatchStartTS, @NewBatchID output

select [NewBatchID] = @NewBatchID
```

Stored procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_CreateBatchRecord') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_CreateBatchRecord
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_CreateBatchRecord
    @BatchDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @BatchID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    /*  PROCEDURE       dbo.[usp_CreateBatchRecord]
        DESCRIPTION:    Creates a new Import Batch record and returns the next BatchID
        PARAMETERS
         + Required:    N/A
         + Optional:    @BatchDate
        OUTPUT:         @BatchID - returns the BatchID of the new Batch record created

        MODIFIED:       N/A

        EXAMPLE(S):
                    -- must set optional parameter to DEFAULT value AND declare output parameter
                    declare @NewBatchID int = null
                    exec dbo.[usp_CreateBatchRecord] DEFAULT,@NewBatchID OUTPUT

                    -- must declare output parameter
                    declare @NewBatchID int = null
                    exec dbo.[usp_CreateBatchRecord] '2016-06-26 15:11:00',@NewBatchID OUTPUT
    */

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    DECLARE @ErrNum INT = NULL
    DECLARE @ErrLineNo INT = NULL

    /* PARAMETER CHECKING */
    if ISNULL(LEN(@BatchDate), 0) = 0
         SET @BatchDate = GETDATE()

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Batch') IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrLineNo = ERROR_LINE()
        SET @ErrNum = ERROR_NUMBER()

        GOTO ERR_HANDLING
    END

    /* INTERNAL VARIABLES */
    DECLARE @CurrentMaxBatchID INT = (SELECT MAX(BatchID) FROM dbo.Batch)
    DECLARE @NextBatchID INT = @CurrentMaxBatchID + 1

    BEGIN TRY
        /* ACTION */
        INSERT INTO dbo.Batch (BatchID, BatchStartTS)
            SELECT @NextBatchID, @BatchDate

        /* RETURN VALUE(S) */
        SELECT @NextBatchID

        GOTO THE_END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrLineNo = ERROR_LINE()
        SET @ErrNum = ERROR_NUMBER()
    END CATCH

ERR_HANDLING:
    RAISERROR('<!> ERROR:  (%i) [%i] %s',16,1,@ErrNum,@ErrLineNo,@ErrMsg) WITH NOWAIT

THE_END:
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: You don't set the value of `@BatchID` anywhere in your procedure. Perhaps you meant to write `SELECT @BatchID = @NextBatchID` instead of making that the result set. (Also, on an unrelated note, this procedure is not safe to call concurrently, which is no problem as long as you're aware of that fact.)

Comment: Also - **be aware** that this approach (`SELECT MAX() + 1`) is ***NOT*** concurrency safe! If multiple users are using this system simultaneously, you **will** end up with **duplicates**. If you're on SQL Server 2012 or newer - you should check out `SEQUENCES` instead which handle all this stuff for you - more or less automagically

Comment: any particular reason you don't just use an auto-increment field for this?

Comment: Also, I would think about refactoring this. There is nothing like good practice, and GOTO is nothing like a good practice.

Comment: You should also look closer at the logic where you check if dbo.Batch is an object. If it isn't you set all your error variables to NULL and then goto to the error block. I would just use a try catch and then raise an exception when it doesn't exist. You could simplify the logic immensely and handle errors nice and clean.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeroen Mostert!  I didn't even realize that I never set the output variable!

As for the concurrency issue, this is a completely separate process that only runs on a nightly basis and nothing else writes to the table(s), so this is a moot point.  However, thanks to everyone for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Jeroen Mostert! I didn't even realize that I never set the output variable!

> [Jeroen Mostert] You don't set the value of @BatchID anywhere in your procedure. Perhaps you meant to write SELECT @BatchID = @NextBatchID instead of making that the result set.